# How to find all comments on a particular linkedin article given articleId?

Tags: c#, api, linkedin-api

I published a [LinkedIn article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/stop-waiting-your-career-recalculate-justin-wilson) and I'm trying to retrieve the comments for this particular article. I obtained the *articleId* by right clicking on the comments button and copying the link address. I get *aritcleId* = 7434836657526032700. Should I use `GET http://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/{post-id}/comments` where {post-id} is same as articleId?

Below is my code after successful *AuthorizationLinkGet* call.

```
string oauth_token = Request.QueryString["oauth_token"];
string oauth_verifier = Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"];
if (oauth_token != null && oauth_verifier != null)
{
    Application["oauth_token"] = oauth_token;
    Application["oauth_verifier"] = oauth_verifier;

    //get access token
    _oauth.Token = oauth_token;
    _oauth.TokenSecret = Application["reuqestTokenSecret"].ToString();
    _oauth.Verifier = oauth_verifier;

    _oauth.AccessTokenGet(oauth_token);

    sLinkedInCommentsURL = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/7434836657526032700/comments";

    string response = _oauth.APIWebRequest("GET", sLinkedInCommentsURL, null);
    lblMessage.Text = response;
}
```

I receive following error:

```
Server Error in '/dreamplaybook' Application.

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Source Error: 


Line 433:            finally
Line 434:            {
Line 435:                webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
Line 436:                responseReader.Close();
Line 437:                responseReader = null;

Source File: c:\inetpub\calendias\dreamplaybook\App_Code\oAuthLinkedIn.cs    Line: 435 

Stack Trace: 


[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6538872
   oAuthLinkedIn.WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest) in c:\inetpub\calendias\dreamplaybook\App_Code\oAuthLinkedIn.cs:435
   oAuthLinkedIn.APIWebRequest(String method, String url, String postData) in c:\inetpub\calendias\dreamplaybook\App_Code\oAuthLinkedIn.cs:357
   adposter.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\calendias\dreamplaybook\adposter.aspx.cs:282
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article ID is not the same field as post id, so that is why you are getting the error you see. The API  does not allow you to get comments from publications.

Comment: Thank you. I'll stay tuned!